# Use defined variables in \ref

Tags: cross-referencing

When trying to use defined variables in `\ref` and I get an error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
```

Here's how I use and define the variable, respectively.

```
\def\SectionnameInstall{section:hironxo\_install}

... \ref{\SectionnameInstall},
```

Apparentely [\ref requires `marker`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing), but I'm not sure whether `\def` meets its criteria. Thank you.

Comment: When asking a question, consider providing a minimal working example (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), to make it easier to help you.  As it is, anyone who wants to play with your code to see what's wrong has to write their own, which makes it less likely that they'll make the effort.

Comment: Side note – I'd use a hyphen `-` here instead of an underscore `_`. They're a lot easier to work with.

Answer (score 4):

The labels for `\label` and `\ref` should be plain strings, best are alphanumeric characters. Special characters should be used with care.
Macros and commands can only be used, if they are fully expandable and expand to some harmless string.

`\_` is defined by `\DeclareRobustCommand`. Therefore it is not expandable and cannot be used. The command is intended to typeset the result, because `_` has a special meaning/category code in math mode.

Technically the label must survive to be put into `\csname` and `\endcsname` to generate the internal macro name, which stores the reference data.

Coming from pdfTeX, most TeX compilers (pdfTeX, LuaTeX, XeTeX) know `\ifincsname`, which can be used to check, if the current context is a building of a macro name inside a `\csname`/`\endcsname` construct.

This can be used to add such a test to the definition of `\_`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\edef\_{%
  \noexpand\ifincsname
    _%
  \noexpand\else
    \noexpand\x@protect\noexpand\_%
    \noexpand\protect
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname _ \endcsname
  \noexpand\fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\SectionnameInstall}{section:hironxo\_install}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Section \ref{\SectionnameInstall} starts
at page \pageref{\SectionnameInstall}

\section{Install}
\label{\SectionnameInstall}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Did not know about `\ifincsname` and I thought about something like that for some time. Is, just out of curiosity, some sort of `\ifinedef` to check if something is being expanded inside an `\edef`?

Comment: @Manuel AFAIK, there is no test for being inside an `\edef` or other expandable contexts (writing to a file, ...) except `\csname`.

Comment: That would be useful, wouldn't it? I mean, one could provide two commands to achieve the same, one fast non-expandable, and another slower but expandable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the defined command is your problem.  Consider the following minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\labeldef{\sectlabel}
\def\sectlabel{sect:examp}
\begin{document}
\label{\labeldef\sectlabel}
Here is a reference with a command in the label:
\pageref{\labeldef\sectlabel}.
\end{document}
```

This compiles without error, and yields the following:

[image: Reference with variable.]

But as soon as I insert `\_`, it doesn't work.  I'm not sure if the underscore here is something you've defined, or if you're just trying to escape a literal underscore.  A literal underscore, however, is safe in labels as a general rule, so if it's the latter, you may want to just delete your backslash and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

The underscore should be escaped for printing it; in a `\label` it mustn't be, because `\_` is a command that produces the set of instructions for printing the underscore.

```
\newcommand\SectionnameInstall{section:hironxo_install}
```

will work, because `_` is legal in the argument of `\label`.